# C# - WCF Client/Server Open a Console on Service Application

Tags: c#, wcf, console, client-server, console-application

the problem is bigger, but I try reducing it to a simpler style:

Lets assume, that I am simply programming a Client/Server Model.
I manage to connect to the Service and can use its function and am able to communicate.
The connection is build up through a configuration file on server site and the client
just connects to it in his Main function by creating a Channelfactory to a WsHTTPEndpoint.
So everything is fine. I can communicate via a console with the server and see
actually what is happening.

But let's imagine now, I am programming a server which provides a service, but also is a client at a different service application.
I want to test whether the connection works and whether I can send some requests,
but there is no console I can write in. Thus, it is hard for me to see,
whether something works or something does not.

How can I start the server and in the same time use a console on it like in a normal client application?

Comment: you ca create logger to log data, and create console application which reads from logger (DB or file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you require this for development purposes, I can recommend unit testing. Before I used unit testing, I would develop somewhat like you describe: create a console server and client and interact with the console client to see whether the send and received data makes sense.

What I do now with unit testing, is that I create small tests that do roughly the same as what I would do manually through the client console. The unit testing approach has the following advantages:

- The tests are small and clear, so I know what I'm testing;
- The tests are repeatable so I know that when all tests pass, the small piece that I tested before still works;
- The tests are easy to run, just as easy as the console client;
- When I have created enough tests, I can use this component in an application where I cannot interact with the console. I don't have to worry anymore whether everything works because the unit tests tested this for me.

This approach has made my live much easier.